# Jest: console shows variable, node throws error

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In the below Jest output you can see seemingly contradictory information on the assignment of module:

```
    ReferenceError: ajaxUrl is not def FAIL  views/admin/__tests__/CurrentCouponListingSection.test.js
  ✕ getCountOfCurrentTargets (8ms)
  ✓ adjustResultMarker (5ms)

  ● getCountOfCurrentTargets

    ReferenceError: ajaxUrl is not defined

       9 |   
      10 |   jQuery.ajax(
    > 11 |     ajaxUrl,
         |     ^
      12 |     {
      13 |       method: 'POST',
      14 |       async: false, 

      at Object.ajaxUrl [as getCountOfCurrentTargets] (views/admin/CurrentCouponListingSection.js:11:5)
      at Object.getCountOfCurrentTargets (views/admin/__tests__/CurrentCouponListingSection.test.js:5:19)

  console.log views/admin/CurrentCouponListingSection.js:4
    http://test.com =====ajaxUrl=====

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.448s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Here is the code Jest calls. Any ideas why node sees `module` as undefined?

```
const testFile = require("../CurrentCouponListingSection.js");

test('getCountOfCurrentTargets', () => {
  expect(testFile.getCountOfCurrentTargets($))
    .toEqual(14);
});
```

.

```
if (typeof 'module' !== undefined) {
  const ajaxUrl = 'http://test.com';
  console.log(ajaxUrl, `=====ajaxUrl=====`); // http://test.com
}    

const getCountOfCurrentTargets = (jQuery) => {
  let countOfCurrentTargets = null;

  jQuery.ajax(
    ajaxUrl,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        action: 'getCountOfCurrentTargets',
      },
      success: response => {
        countOfCurrentTargets = response;
      },
      error: error => console.log(error, `=====error=====`),
    }
  );

  return countOfCurrentTargets;
};
if (typeof 'module' !== undefined) {
  module.exports.getCountOfCurrentTargets = getCountOfCurrentTargets;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you assign that variable, so you're getting a `ReferenceError`. I don't see any 'contradictory' information here. Also, `async: false` is deprecated, provides bad UX, etc. etc.

Comment: Looks like I didn't copy the if block, please see the updated original post

Comment: `const` isn't like `var`, it's scoped to the block it's in. Since it's declared inside an `if` block, it's scoped only to that block, and isn't available outside of it. Either hoist the declaration and conditionally assign (using let or var instead of const) or make the assignment unconditionally.

Comment: I've changed const to let but that didn't work, same error (removing the conditional did though). I do need the conditional there though. Any idea why let also doesn't work here?

Comment: Best guess: because you're still declaring it inside the block instead of hoisting the declaration to the outer scope like I suggested? IDK, I can't see your screen. Just google for "let const var" and read some blog posts or the MDN entries. They should fill you in.

Comment: I think I understand. You are saying to do `let module;` in the outer scope and then reassign it in the if statement. My concern is this might overwrite the `module` variable or throw a duplicate declaration error when it is assigned by node. The whole point of this is to only give the browser a null module variable without interfering with node's assignments

Comment: Sorry, meant to say the intent is to give `ajaxUrl` a default value only when `module` is undefined

Comment: Yup. `let ajaxURL; if (typeof 'module' !== 'undefined') ajaxURL = 'some/path/to/something; `. Also note the quotes around undefined, the `typeof` operator returns a *string*. Note that this can and will still fail for all sorts of reasons like webpack or browserify defining module.